# align in one line text and icon - angular css

Tags: html, css, angular

I have grey row that should contain text and icons, my code:
`{{ trans.dashboard.settings.car.Name| translate }} <i class="fas fa-caret-up"></i>`

this works, but i wanna to text be on the left side as it is now and icon on the right side, so text on the left corner of the container and icon on the right corner, inside corner i write this code:

`i { margin-left: 95px; }`

but when margin left has higher pixels icon goes bellow text, they are not in the same line, how to create bigger space but still make those 2 elements into one line?

Comment: Adjust the width of the element, which contains those two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap both in a span tag. The parent (row) tag should have `display: flex;` and `justify-content: space-between;` declarations.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to set the margin yourself, but rather use flex-boxes in order to achieve this. You can just set

```
display: flex; 
justify-content: space-between;
```

to the row, which will lead to both childs being spaced on the left and right of this row.

Comment: its not working

Comment: If it is not working, you should probably provide the code you tried in your question and explain what exactly is not working. Otherwise we might not be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap the text and icon in a div. Assume that you are calling it container.

```
.container{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;

}
```

Set a minimum width of the container otherwise it will takes the parent width.